# Server stressed by /feed

Tags: feed, apache, cache

I'm debugging a website that my friend has hosted on a VPS that should be perfectly capable of handling a Wordpress installation that gets ~2m monthly visitors. During the last few months, his uptime has gone from 99.9999% to about 97.5%. He's running X Theme and a about a dozen plugins, which I expected would be the cause of some leak or hang, but after looking at the logs it seems much more like concurrent connections is causing the problem, and since 87% of the hits are to feeds for categories, tags, and posts, I'm now inclined to investigate that as the source.

My first inclination was that the feeds would be too small to cause any serious problem, but those feeds are grabbed, fresh without cache, from within one of the most popular health apps. The rate of hits sometimes reaches 1000/minute.

I'm very well capable developer, but I haven't touched wordpress in six years, so I'm a little rusty on the mechanics. Any insight on the following courses of action is appreciated.

- Does my thinking make sense? When the feeds are disabled, the site stands perfectly. When enabled, Apache restarts with the most common error being MaxRequestWorkers exhausted.

  - Wordpress must initialize to use `is_feed()`, so would it possibly make sense to roll my own feed server that simply uses the Wordpress database without the Wordpress overhead?
  - Is there a suitable feed caching plugin? I've found W3 purportedly does, but I see no evidence of it working once installed and activated.